# Store a line of data into a file

Tags: c, io, character-encoding, char, huffman-code

I have been working on my Huffman project. Almost finished, now the only thing I need to do is to store in an output file. Here is my decode function.

```
void decode(struct Node * root, int * encodeString) 
{
    int i;
    struct Node * temp = root;
    for (i = 0; encodeString[i] != -1; i++) 
{

            if (encodeString[i] == 1) 
    {
                    temp = temp -> right;
            } 
    else 
    {
                    temp = temp -> left;
            }

            if (isLeaf(temp)) 
    {
                    printf("%c", temp -> character);
                    temp = root;
            }

    }

}
```

Calling in main function

```
decode(start, encodedString);
    printf("\n");
```

Result of decompression:

```
Fred Fish 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

I will later call it in the main function. When I call, the decoded string would be printed. Is there a way to read these characters. I did not go with fgets() because I don't know the size of the chars. I tried scanf("%99c", line) but it does not work, please advise

Comment: question is to store or read ?

Comment: @LearningC The question is to put out an output file of the decompressed

Comment: Check about file read/write operations in c.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to print something onto a file you first have to open the desired file.
Use function [fopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) to do so.

If you set the mode parameter to "r" you will just be able to read from that file. If you want to write, as you said, use the option "w".

You can write on the file by using one of the available functions such as fwrite. But there are quite a few others, just do your research.

When you're finished remember to close the file you have previously opened though a call to [fclose](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose).